# 401 unauthorized error only in IE and Edge when using outlook.office365.com/owa

Tags: web-part, user-profile, outlook

I'm displaying users photos by using the below url

```
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=XXX.com&UA=0&size=HR64x64&sc=1500867903362
```

It works perfectly in Chrome always and the pictures display:)
But never works in IE and Edge :)

Any ideas why I'm getting the 401 unauthorized?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct URL to get user's photo is:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/userphoto.aspx?
size=L&accountname=user.name%40tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```

You can change the size to `S or M or L` which stands for `Small or Medium or Large`.

Most likely your ajax request is cross domain and will be blocked by browser's [Same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Not 100% sure why its working in chrome, did you try it Chrome's InCognito mode as well ? Could be that you have visited the profile page once and this set some cookies which allowed you to get the profile picture.

Try and visit the user profile page in IE/Edge and then you will also be able to view the image.

To get around this problem, use the URL mentioned above.

Comment: Hi Gautam, Do have an idea where the actual pic is stored in SharePoint?.As after changing it no pic come up :(

Comment: Check [this](http://paulryan.com.au/2016/user-photos-office-365/) and [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3185286/information-about-profile-picture-synchronization-in-office-365) link. In my experience, after you change your profile picture it takes anything from couple of hours to 3-4 days for the updated profile picture to be reflected.